# VB.NET CDate lops off 12:00:00 AM from 1/19/2021 12:00:00 AM

Tags: vb.net

Environment: VS.Net 2013, .NET FW 4.5.2

We ran into something curious with CDate and datetime strings with midnight as the time.

When we pass in non-midnight datetimes we get

`CDate("1/18/2021 9:00:00 PM")` returns #1/18/2021 9:00:00 PM#

`CDate("1/19/2021 12:01:00 AM")` returns #1/19/2021 12:01:00 AM#

These are both expected results.

However when we pass in:

`CDate("1/19/2021 12:00:00 AM")` it only returns #1/19/2021# without the time portion.

Here's a screenshot of the value at runtime, at a break point: https://www.screencast.com/t/r0WOxWB0GGU

Is there any reason why time is omitted?

Update: this issue is solved in later releases of VS .NET and we have a programmatic workaround for the current environment.

Comment: You cannot "lose" the time portion because it's an integral part of the `DateTime` type. It may be omitted when formatting the date to a string or to a date literal because it defaults to midnight when omitted. Similarly, `42#` is exactly equal to `42.00#`.

Comment: I'll reword my original post to remove "lose"

Comment: You have wrapped the value with **#** symbols. Do you mean that this is what is output by the VS datetime visualizer during debug?  The omission of the time value of 12:00:00 AM was normal in the pre-VS2015 editions.  In the newer VS editions the full datetime value is displayed.

Comment: If you are actually hard-coding the date and time as you have shown then you shouldn't be using `CDate` in the first place. If you just type `1` rather than `CInt("1")` then you should use `#1/18/2021 9:00:00 PM#` rather than `CDate("1/18/2021 9:00:00 PM")`, because that's a `Date` literal. If you're getting text input from the user then that's a different matter, of course, and I suspect that that is what you're actually doing. If it's WinForms though, you ought to be using a `DateTimePicker` and getting a `DateTime` directly from the `Value` property.

Comment: @TnTinMn I am using VS.NET 2013 and, correct, the watch window displays #1/18/2021 9:00:00 PM#, #1/19/2021 12:01:00 AM#, #1/19/2021# respectively for the CDate examples above.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the dates are actually in a string variable which are read in from a SQL DataReader. I have oversimplified the code above with hardcoded values because whether its a variable or a string value, the behavior is the same: CDate omits the time when its a datetime string including midnight but includes the time for any other datetime string.

Comment: @JeffMergler "the dates are actually in a string variable" <- there's one big problem.

Comment: As suggested, the problem is that you are storing the data as text. Do you store numbers as text? I would think not, so why stores dates/times as text? SQL Server has numerous data types dedicated to dates and/or times so you should be using the appropriate one of those. That is most likely `datetime2`. Any of the data types that supports a date will map to `DateTime` in .NET so you will ALWAYS get a date and time value.

Comment: That said, it still shouldn't matter because `CDate` will ALWAYS create a `DateTime` value anyway and a `DateTime` value ALWAYS has a time portion, even if that portion is zero. The best solution is to change your data type in the database and just treat every date/time value the same. Your remaining code may still need adjustment though, and it definitely will if you are unable to change the database schema now. You might consider posting a new question about the actual issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the dates are stored in SQL Server as datetime. This is not an issue with that, its an issue with CDate and datetime strings containing midnight and how its represented and causing an issue downstream. We're beating a dead horse here. Thanks again for your help though. I gave you upvotes where appropriate.

Comment: If your data is stored correctly in the database then why are you dealing with `Strings` at all? When you query a SQL Server database containing `datetime` data then you will get `DateTime` values in your VB code. As such, there's no need to use `CDate` in the first place. If you are using `CDate` to convert `Strings` then you must have created those `String` from the `DateTimes` you got from the database in the first place, which you should not have done. Also, `CDate` is not the problem as it will produce a `DateTime` with a zero time`. You must be converting that back to a `String` again.

Comment: The issue is solved, thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's purely about how the VB debugger represents `DateTime` literals. In 24-hour time, 12:00 AM is 00:00, so basically "no time". As such, the debugger just doesn't show the time. That doesn't actually affect what's in the `DateTime` value though.

As suggested in one of the comments, the behaviour of VS may well have changed, as I'm not seeing that behaviour in VS 2019. Maybe too many people were confused as you are. In that case, your version of VS will likely make that change in representation in code as well as in the debugger. Try writing this code:

```vb
Dim dt = #1/1/2000 12:00 AM#
```

In VS 2019, I typed that and it stayed as it was. I suspect that your version will change that to:

```vb
Dim dt = #1/01/2000#
```

It doesn't matter though. It's just a representation. The data is unaffected.

Whenever you want to display a `DateTime` value to the user, you must convert it to a `String` and display that. What format is used in the output is completely within your control, you if you want to include the time then you specify that when you do that conversion. That is completely unrelated to what the VB debugger displays.

Comment: I updated the original post with a screen grab of the behavior and I also confirmed that #1/1/2000 12:00 AM# does return #1/1/2000# Regarding `It doesn't matter though. It's just a representation. The data is unaffected.` Well, it does if you're going to add or subtract hours based on the users timezone and the math breaks due to the lack of time. We'll just code a workaround in this particular case until we update to a later version of .NET and VS.NET.

Comment: @JeffMergler The time is not missing: it just isn't shown in the debugger.

Comment: I can confirm this @AndrewMorton. If I call CDate("1/19/2021 12:00:00 AM").AddHours(-3) I correctly get #"1/18/2021 9:00:00 PM"#. So real prob is our code reacts badly to return of CDate("1/19/2021 12:00:00 AM") as #1/19/2021#. Our code interprets this as date only and causes a downstream prob when we attempt a timezone adjustment for the user. Code falsely skips timezone adjustment bc we only do a timezone adjustment on datetime values, not date only. Anyway I'm getting into the weeds on an old legacy app and we can work around it now that we understand what's going on. Thanks everyone.